# create users before running tests DRF

Tags: django, django-testing

i want to run django tests,
but i want to create some users before i run the test and the users' username will be attribute of the class and can be shared in all tests somthing like this:

```
class DoSomeTests(TestCase):


    def setup_createusers(self):
             self.usr1 = create_user1()
             self.usr2 = create_user1()
             self.usr3 = create_user1()
    def test_number_one(self):
               use self.user1/2/3
    def test_number_two(self):
               use self.user1/2/3
    def test_number_three(self):
               use self.user1/2/3
```

how can i do it becuase every time i tried the test dont recognize the self's attributes
ive tried use setupclass and setUp but nothing happend

cretae users before running tests

Answer (score 3):

Generally (and personally) since `setUpTestData` was introduced I use this one but you can use `setUp` also based on your approach and what you need.
In order to use `setUpTestData` you need to put a `class decorator` and approach it with `cls` instead of `self` since you want to set up data for the whole TestCase, something like:

```
class TestViews(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user1 = User.objects.create_user(........)
        cls.user2 = User.objects.create_user(........)
        cls.user3 = User.objects.create_user(........)
```

Then in your tests, in order to access (and log in) each user you can use this:

```
   def test_number_one(self):
        test_user = self.user1
        self.client.force_login(test_user)
```

Comment: if i want to sent requets? 
somthing like this:`create1 = self.client.post(url, usr1)`
how i do it with cls?

Comment: yeah thats right. `self.client.post(url, {'user_role': 'customer'})`